# How can I add a shortcut of a file to the start menu?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I have an image file (JPG format) in the Document folder of Windows 10. I would like to make a shortcut button in the start menu so that I can access that image very quickly. How can I do this?

In case of .exe file, there is 'Pin to Start' menu in the context menu when I right click the file name, but there is no such feature for the image file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First add it to the *actual* Start Menu (i.e. the program list). It's an ordinary folder that already holds mostly shortcuts, so open `shell:start menu` or `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and drag a shortcut of your JPG file there.

The shortcut will now show up among "all programs", where it will have a "Pin to Start" option.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Start Menu' folder containing a shortcut to a random .png file]
[image: Screenshot of the actual Start Menu program list displaying the shortcut, with its context menu open]

<sup>(In older Windows versions up to 2000, simply placing an item directly in this folder (i.e. not in the Programs subfolder) *was* how you would "pin" it at the top of the Start Menu. The distinction was lost with the redesigned Start Menu in Windows XP, which had an explicit "pin" command.)</sup>

Comment: For any future user, opening `shell:start menu` can be done by clicking Win+R and pasting it there and clicking enter.